# Pause in android voice recorder

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am using MediaRecorder in my app for recording voice data. I want to implement pause as it is not available in SDK.
I am recording voice to temporary file. When user clicks pause button, I will append that recorded voice to a file, which is opened initially when app launches.
The things are not happening as expected. Can anyone help me?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

### Edit

I have tried out with this code.

    `recorder.stop();`

```
    recorder.reset();
    System.out.println("recording stopped");
    File inFile = new File(recorderOutFile);
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        recordFileStream = new FileOutputStream(recordingFile, true);
        int size = fin.available();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[size];
        System.out.println("Buffer size:" + size + "\td:"
                + new String(buffer));
        fin.read(buffer);
        recordFileStream.write(buffer);
        recordFileStream.flush();
        recordFileStream.close();
        fin.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you pls paste code and elaborate what u have implemted yet and what is not working?

Comment: @Ashwini,Hi i too facing the pause problem. how could you solve this pause problem? please help me.

Comment: can any one post answer for this.... :)